# How to remove part of a string in a some format

Tags: java, datetime-format

I am getting time and date in this format **2012-03-14 12:33:30.000** from server. I want to remove the time part and keep just the date part like this **2012-03-14**.

I get all outputs in this format and would like to know how I can remove the time part for all. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you modify a string in java? Start with that and you will find your answer.

Comment: `str = str.substring(0,10);`

Comment: How do you get this time data, what is your object?

Comment: this works @notyou

Comment: That’s a perfectly valid way of looking at it, @Deadpool. As you can see from the answers, there are others too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As you can read on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you are supposed to search and research before asking. I am downvoting because I see no sign that you have done so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play with Java time, you could parse the source with the relevant format, then format it back to fit your needs :

```
String str = "2012-03-14 12:33:30.000";

DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTimeFormatter targetFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, sourceFormatter);

System.out.println(targetFormatter.format(dateTime));
```

Comment: I agree that this is the best and nicest approach. Still better, use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` as your second formatter. The format has already been defined for us, so no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#ofPattern` requires API level 26 Oreo, which is only 5.7% of devices.

Comment: @YousufSohail It sounds like you are talking about Android? (1) I saw nothing in the question mentioning Android. (2) If you want to use this answer on not-brand-new Android, get the ThreeTenABP library, and it will work fine. See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of achieving this is like this

```
str = str.substring(10);
```

Another way is like this

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = fmt.parse(yourString);//yourString is your String variable
date.toString();//or whatever
```

Comment: You mean `str = str.substring(0,10);` *I want to remove the time part and keep just the date part*. Also if you're recommending a date/time class, consider [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and not `Date`.

Comment: you can format it like that also, check the updated answer

Comment: Please do not recommend the usage of `SimpleDateFormat` which is horribly outdated. Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Comment: I agree that using standard date-time classes for the task is a good idea. However please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the split method, for example:

if you having the `date = 2012-03-14 12:33:30.000` you can do

```
String text[] = date.split(' ') - (with a space in between
 '') and get de text[0]
```

Comment: What language and library are you using? (The question was tagged java.)

Comment: The language is Java and the library is Date

Comment: Thanks for replying. [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) hasn’t got methods `getFullYear` nor `getFullMonth` (nor `split` for that matter). Your answer won’t work.

Answer (score -2):

First parse your date string to Java Date object which will contain both date and time, then get the date from that Date object.

Comment: A good idea, but vaguely described. Some of the other answers are somewhat more precise about the same.